# Excel and MS Access: Method 'open' of object '_Recordset' failed

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am writing this code in Excel to insert into an access database.

```
INSERT INTO `C:\Users\ABCBASDkJAJDSKk\Desktop\asdgahsdguu.accdb`.`Table1` Values ('ABCD', 'ABCD','ABCD,ABCD','NA','Success','Several of the above','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','AB',12)
```

I am getting the error Method open of object Recordset failed at the rs.open statement.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Below is the code

```
Sub merge_update()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Darwin Merge Set")
lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim cmd1 As ADODB.Command
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New Connection
strFile = "C:\Users\ABCBASDkJAJDSKk\Desktop\asdgahsdguu.accdb"
cn.Provider = " Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 "
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Persist Security Info=false;"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
cn.Open

For i = 7 To lastrow

    src = Range("b" & i).Value
    tar = Range("c" & i).Value
    dmc = Range("d" & i).Value
    gl = Range("e" & i).Value
    mo = Range("f" & i).Value
    msa = Range("g" & i).Value
    fm = Range("h" & i).Value
    rsnm = Range("i" & i).Value
    em = Range("j" & i).Value
    sa = Range("k" & i).Value
    rbsc = Range("l" & i).Value
    qao = Range("m" & i).Value
    qac = Range("n" & i).Value
    lo = Range("o" & i).Value
    mpl = Range("p" & i).Value
    mon = Range("q" & i).Value

    stmt = "INSERT INTO `" & strFile & "`.`Table1`"
    stmt = stmt & " Values ('" & src & "', '" & tar & "','" & dmc & "','" & gl & "','" & mo & "','" & msa & "','" & fm & "','" & rsnm & "','" & em & "','" & sa & "','" & rbsc & "','" & qao & "','" & qac & "','" & mpl & "'," & mon & ") "

    cmd1.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd1.CommandText = stmt
    Set rs = cmd1.Execute



Next i

cn.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using a command object, you want to replace the RecordSet with a Command.  The recordset is where the values come back from the database.

here is a link with a lot of good examples for you.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168336/en-us

One example (the New in the Dim cmd1 line is important.

```
 Dim cmd1 As New ADODB.Command

 ' Recordset Open Method #2:  Open via Command.Execute(...)
   Conn1.ConnectionString = AccessConnect
   Conn1.Open
   Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1
   Cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees"
   Set Rs1 = Cmd1.Execute
   Rs1.Close
   Conn1.Close
   Conn1.ConnectionString = ""
```

Comment: I have actually used the way that I had used earlier in a previous version and it had worked. I tried this method too but it doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: @user3710095 So what did you try and what was the error?  generally sending data to a db you want to use a command object.

Comment: I used    
        cmd1.ActiveConnection = cn
        cmd1.CommandText = stmt
        Set rs = cmd1.Execute  
cmd1.activeconnection=cn gives me an error saying object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: cmd1.activeconnection=cn

Comment: cmd1.activeconnection=cn gives me an error saying object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: @user3710095 That means "An invalid variable is being referenced." want to update your question with the new code?  Did you declare the cmd1 like this " Dim Cmd1 As New adodb.Command " ?

Comment: Yes, I did. That and the statements that I have mentioned earlier are the only changes

Comment: @user3710095 Did you try debugging and see what the values were of all the variables at that point before the attempt at assignment?

Comment: @user3710095 If you update the code in the question to reflect what you've done I can try and see if anything sticks out.  I'm a C# guy so I might not see that actual problem.  It builds fine just throws an error at run time.

Comment: @user3710095 you don't have a 'New' in the dim line for command  Dim cmd1 As NEW ADODB.Command

Comment: What's happening is you don't have an actual Command object at the time you are trying to set the connection.